# ImportTool from sqoop.tool not applicable for the arguments (org.apache.sqoop.SqoopOptions)

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

We are trying for Sqoop import using Java which works fine until I try to remove the deprecated com.cloudera.sqoop.SqoopOptions from ImportTool as shown in the code snippet below. 
apache.sqoop.SqoopOptions could be a substitute for package cloudera.sqoop.SqoopOptions but ImportTool only supports cloudera package, which is deprecated. 
What could be the other way of writing this code ? Please help.

```
import org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool;
import org.apache.sqoop.SqoopOptions;
import org.apache.sqoop.SqoopOptions.InvalidOptionsException;
//import com.cloudera.sqoop.SqoopOptions;
//import com.cloudera.sqoop.SqoopOptions.InvalidOptionsException;

public int sqoopImport(String name) throws ThrowIt {
try {
        ImportTool importTool = new ImportTool();
        SqoopOptions sqoopOptions = importTool.parseArguments(arg.toArray(new String[0]), configuration, null,
                true);
        importTool.validateOptions(sqoopOptions); //Error here, ImportTool needs sqoopOption from cloudera which is deprecated.
        returnValue = importTool.run(sqoopOptions); //Error here, ImportTool needs sqoopOption from cloudera which is deprecated.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Download this jar:- [enter link description here](http://%20https://code.google.com/p/sshxcute/)**

public class TestSSH {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

```
// Initialize a ConnBean object, the parameter list is IP, username, password

ConnBean cb = new ConnBean("192.168.56.102", "root","hadoop");

// Put the ConnBean instance as parameter for SSHExec static method getInstance(ConnBean) to retrieve a singleton SSHExec instance
SSHExec ssh = SSHExec.getInstance(cb);          
// Connect to server
ssh.connect();
CustomTask sampleTask1 = new ExecCommand("echo $SSH_CLIENT"); // Print Your Client IP By which you connected to ssh server on Horton Sandbox
System.out.println(ssh.exec(sampleTask1));
CustomTask sampleTask2 = new ExecCommand("sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://192.168.56.101:3316/mysql_db_name --username=mysql_user --password=mysql_pwd --table mysql_table_name --hive-import -m 1 -- --schema default");
ssh.exec(sampleTask2);
ssh.disconnect();
```

}
}

Comment: Could you add a short description explaining your code?

Comment: basically this code will create a connection with that machine wherever your sqoop install for this connection you will have to pass IP and Pass of that machine in this object. that object will be ConnBean cb = new ConnBean("yourIP", "Account","Pass");  then that will try to login in that machine with the help of ssh. now we will be a ssh client we can fair that query of sqoop using machine command from Java. command will taken by CustomTask sampleTask1 = new ExecCommand("echo $SSH_CLIENT"); this obj (here we are login as a client ), (ssh.exec(sampleTask1) this will execute above query.

Comment: again you will have to pass your main query which will be a sqoop- import like that:   CustomTask sampleTask2 = new ExecCommand("sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://192.168.56.101:3316/mysql_db_name --username=mysql_user --password=mysql_pwd --table mysql_table_name --hive-import -m 1 -- --schema default"); and finally execute this one as well . HOPE THIS WILL CLEAR YOUR DOUBT.